# Call JavaScript async function in flutter dart future returns THIS: (a string) [Object Promise]

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web, dart-js-interop

I have a flutter web where i have a JavaScript function like this:

```
async function doSomething(value) {
   let x = await something(x);
   return x
}
```

When I'm now in dart, I have:

```
final result = await js.context.callMethod('doSomething', ['someValue']));
```

This returns `[object Promise]` when I print it. I don’t understand why I get this.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `dart:html` and use `window.console.log(result)`